# Information asymmetry models

Tags: finance, finance-mathematics, financial-engineering, information

I am searching for some textbook in financial mathematics that presents information asymmetry models (maybe more advanced models), so as to make some practice. Does anbody know such a book?

Comment: This probably isn't what you want but it has a lot of relevant references in the bibliography. https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2013/RJ-2013-008/RJ-2013-008.pdf

Comment: @mark leeds it is something to start!

Comment: @Nav89 hello, did you find any model? I search for the same topic. But I could not. Please suggest me!

Comment: @markleeds I could not find anything. Please help me?

Comment: Hi: not sure what you're looking for but what's wrong with A) easley, deprado and o'hara OR B) kyle or C) glosten AND milgrom ? The last two are kind of classics in information asymmetry in markets.